# How to I bind Current User automatically in Asp.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm studying and researching about Object Relationships. I want to include the User object as a property into another object.
Here is my code:

```
public class ToDo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public ToDo ParentTask { get; set; }
    }
```

I understand that while I execute the Create ToDo method, I can search for current logged in userid and then pass that Id to the ToDo object. But what I intend to do is to automatically bind user object to the ToDo object when a ToDo is created. How can I achieve this objective?
I have searched the internet but couldn't find a satisfying answer yet.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: if it's readonly. Maybe you can try: `public ApplicationUser User { get { return //your logged in user } }`

Comment: This is a very broad question. What type of user? Integrated security? Local DB? OAuth? SAML? What have you tried?

Comment: Why not just create a constructor, pass in required parameters, execute a store query and set it to the `User` property.

Comment: It's not a broad question, he's using `ASP.NET MVC` with `EntityFramework`

Comment: @Khanh TO, Thanks Ok I did that but still it's not filling the object after ToDo is created.

Comment: @MattRowland ApplicationUser object

Answer (score 1):

I assume each `User` has a `ToDo` list...

So...

```
public class ApplicationUser 
{
    // ... other properties
    public ICollection<ToDo> ToDos { get; set; }
}
```

Now whenever you wish to add a new Todo...

```
user.ToDos.Add(todoItem);
```

If you want to carry on doing it the way you've shown, then you will also need the property `public string UserId { get; set; }` on the `ToDo` class.

When creating a new `ToDo` item, you can fill the caller UserId onto the `ToDo.UserId` property.

Keep in mind this will only assign the item to the correct user, it won't grab the user from the data store with all their properties. To do that, you must explicitly request the user from the data store first.

Comment: Ok I added the property
public string UserId { get; set; } on the ToDo class.
Thanks. But how to get it filled automatically by ModelBinding.

See my current ToDo controller create action is this:
`public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description,DueDate,Done")] ToDo toDo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.ToDoes.Add(toDo);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(toDo);
        }
`
How to make it fill UserId as well.

Comment: Even then, I suppose that is easy, but I want to implement the Aggregation relationship. I want ToDo object to have User object not just a userId in the database.

Comment: @TheSarfaraz `string userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();`

Comment: Is there a possibility that I can do something in ToDo Model Class, instead of adding this in the Controller Create Method?

Comment: Why don't you do it the first way that I've shown you? call the user from the database using the current id

Comment: No, don't put that logic in the model class, it has no business being there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104011/discussion-between-thesarfaraz-and-aydin-adn).

Answer (score 1):

You can create constructors and use them to set your `User` property to desired user, it can be the current user or any user using it's id. You just need to change the `ToDo` class.

```
public class ToDo
{
    [NotMapped]
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    [NotMapped]
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public ToDo ParentTask { get; set; }

    public ToDo(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        // code to search user in to given context and set it to `User` Property
    }

    public ToDo(string userId)
    {
        // code to search user using UserManager by Id, can change it to include email, username or any other property and set it to `User` Property
    }

}
```

You can also try this, it gets the current user. It will automatically bind to current user.

```
public ApplicationUser User
    {
        get
        {
            return UserManager.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
        set
        {
            User = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I want to implement this editted version, this means I dont have to create those signinmanager and suermanager objects, right?

Comment: You will have to create the `UserManager` as it is used to get the user, however `SignInManager` is not necessary, mistakenly put it there. Going to remove it.

Comment: I have added `[NotMapped]` attribute in case you are using this class for code-first database...